# How can I make fresh burger buns like Hardees?

Tags: baking, bread, hamburgers

I am pretty new to baking and having recently just come back from Saudi Arabia I was privileged to visit the Hardees food chain (non in the UK where I live) and fallen in love with their fresh baked buns.

Does anyone know how to copy or come close to there burger bread buns? Can I can other buns and add butter or something close?

Hardees also wrap it in a foil packaging and since I suspect they use butter for that extra soft velvet feel it makes it more better as the bun melts with the cheese and burger inside the packaging.

Here is a clip too

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nvth7WJucQ

Thanks

Comment: I've never had Hardees (UK represent!) but they look like a brioche-style bun to me. Happily enough, that ties in with the bun I make for my burgers, for which I use this recipe: http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/2009/07/light-brioche-burger-buns/ Try it now, thank me later. (For the record, mine always come out much darker and more even coloured than Smitten Kitchen's anaemic looking things. They taste awesome - a bit like croissants, thanks to the egg and butter).

Comment: I've never heard of Hardees (UK massive) but you might want to get inspiration from Heston's classic burger bun recipe http://www.insearchofheston.com/2014/05/how-to-make-hestons-perfect-cheeseburger-recipe-from-in-search-of-perfection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter, Hardees lists the ingredients for their [Soft Baked Buns](http://www.hardees.com/system/pdf_menus/10/original/H_RB_Ingredients_Allergens_2013.pdf?1384481568) on their website.

From there, we can gain that the main ingredients are:

```
All Purpose White Flour
Water
Sugar
Soybean Oil
Yeast
```

Additionally, it contains less than 2% of:

```
Wheat Gluten
Salt
Maltodextrin
Food Starch-Modified
DATEM
Xanthan Gum
Whey
Dextrin
Mixed Triglycerides
Enzymes
Ascorbic Acid
Acesulfame Potassium
Maltitol
Neotame
Turmeric
Annato
```

And their Egg mixture for Basting:

```
Whole Eggs
Citric Acid diluted with water
```

I would probably knock out the following:

```
Wheat Gluten
Maltodextrin
Food Starch-Modified
DATEM
Dextrin
Mixed Triglycerides
Enzymes
Acesulfame Potassium
Maltitol
Neotame
```

Which leaves as the "less than 2% of" list:

```
Salt
Xanthan Gum
Turmeric
Annato
Ascorbic Acid
Whey
```

Comment: Which unfortunately only gives us part of the puzzle - ratios, process, and cooking time are all still a mystery.

Comment: Correct @logophobe. I was hoping someone else could chime in with those as I couldn't fit what I wrote in a comment :(

Comment: Thank you for the post. So there is no directions of how you would approach this. I do not know what `Xanthan Gum` is and guess being an amateur would have to get a baking bread machine too?

Comment: Yes - my apologies for no directions. I only found the ingredients and posted them in hopes that someone else would be able to post directions. As for Xanthan Gum - its a thickening agent that is plant derived and can be [purchased](http://www.bobsredmill.com/xanthan-gum.html) in powder form. As for the directions, I would follow [this recipes directions](http://www.chefsteps.com/activities/brioche-burger-buns)

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid a bread baking machine is probably counterproductive here. Each machine is limited to very few types of bread. If you want to replicate a certain type, doing it by hand is the way to go, unless you have access to the same machine as the original used